# iOS7 specific code in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to use iOS7 specific code in certain places, usually this has not caused much problem until now. I tried some different approaches for the first if statement, the one below seams to be the recommended way. None works. The error i get is this:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey
  Referenced from: /Users/pese/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/0A4B5156-84D8-41DE-C9D1-2E4C9DB38983/aaaa.app/aaaa
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /Users/pese/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/0A4B5156-84D8-41DE-C9D1-2E4C9DB38983/aaaa.app/aaaa
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

And my code:

```
if ( &UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey != nil )
{
    id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> tc = self.topViewController.transitionCoordinator;
    [tc animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        CGRect newRect = _inRect;
        if ([context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey] == [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0])
        {
            newRect = _outRect;
        }
        _backButton.frame = newRect;
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        BOOL enableSwipeToGoBack = YES;
        if ([context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey] == [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] && ![context isCancelled])
        {
            enableSwipeToGoBack = NO;
        }
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = enableSwipeToGoBack;
    }];
}
```

If i just put NO in the if statement it works but i guess that the compiler removes the code during compilation. If i replace the two `UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey` with `nil` it also works. Also the symbol causing the error is defined in UIKit/UIViewControllerTransitioning.h and look like this:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION:

Make UIKit framework optional and change if test to:

```
NSString * const *exists = &UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey;
if ( exists != NULL )
    ....
```

Comment: You need to do a runtime test to see if the method is there.  You can either test the iOS version or test whether the class supports the method.

Comment: `UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey != nil` is fine, but you have to add UIKit as an "optional" framework, i. e. use weak linkage.

Comment: @HotLicks If the symbols are appropriately exported weak symbols, then OP just has to use the proper linker command. Note that OP isn't using a method of a class but an external constant. (Also, I'd say that testing features is better than testing the OS version.)

Comment: @hotLicks Just testing won't work since the code is still being compiled with a symbol that don't exist.

Comment: @H2CO3 i thought i tried this already but i actually only changed it in thee pods setting, i will try to change in my app an see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The problem obviously occurs during linking, not when running the app. He has to compile with iOS 7 as a base SDK, iOS 6 as deployment target and do the run time check for iOS 7 before using UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey. The result should run correctly on iOS 6.

Comment: @HotLicks You were right, i needed to make the UIKit framework optional. But the weirdest thing is when doing the check i HAVE(!) to do this:     ´NSString * const *exists = &UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey;
if ( exists != NULL )´ no other way works. just testing the variable gives bad access and testing the address(&) of the variable always returns true.. I don't quiet get it, guessing it has to have something to do with objective-c auto dereferencing pointers..

Comment: Just FYI, the latest Apple tech talks cover this very topic and offer up some great tips on solving common problems associated with OS-version-specific code. They are worth watching. IIRC the specific video is Architecting Modern Apps, Part 2.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, testing the features is typically better, but you can use a compiler directive to conditionally compile based on the OS version.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    // target is iOS
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 70000
    // target is lower than iOS 7.0
    NSLog(@"This message should only appear if iOS version is 6.x or lower");
    #else
    // target is at least iOS 7.0
    #endif
#endif
```